# Как вычислить расстояние между точками через структуры?

Tags: структуры, c++

C клавиатуры вводятся координаты точек на плоскости в виде строк, представляющих пару в формате (х,у). Координаты должны быть извлечены и помещены в вектор точек (точка - пользовательский тип данных структура). Вычислить и вывести расстояние от всех точек до первой точки.

---

Похоже, задача решается через т. Пифагора sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2). Как приплести сюда структуры?

Comment: Сделайте структуру "Точка" (Point), которая будет хранить координаты х и у. Создайте в этой структуре функцию, которая будет получать в качестве аргумента ссылку на другую точку и возвращать расстояние до нее

Comment: Очевидно, что надо описать точку в виде структуры

    struct point {
       double x, y;
    };
    ...
    struct point p1, p2;
    ...
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf $lf", &p1.x, &p1.y, &p2.x, &p2.y);

Дальше, надеюсь, все понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Единственное, что приходит в голову - хранить точки в структуре:

```
struct sPoint {
    float x;
    float y;
}
```

Можно у структуры объявить конструктор со строкой на вход и убрать туда парсинг.